# Update paths of pinned files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, pinning

I'm trying to find the locations of the pinned files so I can update the shortcuts to a different drive letter, but I can't find where they are saved. Can anyone help? I'm looking specifically for the files I've pinned to an application, not applications that I've pinned to the taskbar. So when I rightclick on the pinned Excel app icon, I've got a list of pinned files. I can get the properties of them, but the property dialog boxes don't let you change the path.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're referring to is "Jumplists". Unfortunately, the existing jumplists destination can't be edited. However there are third-party tools that allows you create custom Jumplists as you wish. Here are some references:

jumplist-extender - A custom jump list creator for any program on Windows 7 - Google Project Hosting : https://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/

Jump List History location?https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/92b90228-2f08-4558-9c4d-6e66e103a5cf/jump-list-history-location?forum=w7itprogeneral